# IF statement in WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two related tables; categories and subscriptions. Relationship of categories->subscriptions does not always exist. So I need something like:

```
SELECT * FROM categories
LEFT JOIN subscriptions 
ON subscriptions.category_id = categories.category_id 
WHERE
 IF EXISTS(subscriptions.is_enable)
  categories.type = 'premium' AND
  subscriptions.is_enable = 1
ELSE
  categories.type = 'premium' AND
```

Is there any way to write condition like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your condition logically like this:

```
SELECT * FROM categories
LEFT JOIN subscriptions 
ON subscriptions.category_id = categories.category_id 
WHERE (subscriptions.is_enable IS NULL OR subscriptions.is_enable = 1)
  AND categories.type = 'premium'
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Since all the terms inside your if/else clauses are Logically ANDed, then you can simply group them logically.

```
SELECT * FROM categories
LEFT JOIN subscriptions 
ON subscriptions.category_id = categories.category_id 
WHERE
  (EXISTS(subscriptions.is_enable) AND 
  categories.type = 'premium' AND
  subscriptions.is_enable = 1)
OR
  (categories.type = 'premium' AND...)
```